# Updating values in one table based on another

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following `UPDATE` query, but something is wrong when executing.
I'm trying to update values in *table1* with values in table *import_data*, but I need the id from table *ids*... So the table *ids* links *table1* and *import Simple, isn't it?

```
UPDATE table1
INNER JOIN import_data ON (
    import_data.id = (
        SELECT customer_id 
        FROM ids
        INNER JOIN table1 ON (
            table1.id = ids.link
        )
        WHERE ids.type = 'NORMAL'
    )
)
SET table1.name = import_data.name;
```

**table1**

```
| id       | name      |
|----------|-----------|
| AA-00001 | Company 1 |
| AA-00002 | Company 2 |
| AA-00003 | Company 3 |
```

**import_data**

```
| id     | name              |
|--------|-------------------|
| 401000 | Updated company 1 |
| 401001 | Updated company 2 |
| 401002 | Company 3         |
```

**ids**

```
| link     | id     | type   |
|----------|--------|--------|
| AA-00001 | 401000 | NORMAL |
| AA-00002 | 401001 | NORMAL |
| AA-00003 | 401002 | NORMAL |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
update table1 t1
inner join (
    select idata.name, ids.link
    from import_data idata
    join ids on ids.id = idata.id
    where ids.type = 'NORMAL'
) x
on x.link = t1.id
set t1.name = x.name
```

**Demo**   [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c188/1)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's depends on database you're using. The relevant post is answered here - [How can I do an UPDATE statement with JOIN in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

I dont have mysql to check it, but it should work the way you want. Please check.

```
               UPDATE table1
                INNER JOIN ids
                ON table1.id= ids.link
                INNER JOIN import_data 
                on import_data.id = ids.id
                SET table1.name = import_data.name
                WHERE ids.type = 'NORMAL';
```